# How do I create a home screen button with a tel:// URI?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-configurator

I can create a home screen button with a tel:// uri using Apple Configurator, but this requires installing a profile on the phone and is not that straight forward.

What I would like to do is create a home screen button with and icon that is my picture and that when tapped invokes a tel URI instead of an HTTP URI without mucking about with custom profiles and the Apple Configurator.

It would be best, of course, if this was something I could walk someone (an older someone) through over the phone or with a Clarify document.

(I have elderly parents and inlaws that are now finding making calls on their iPhones confusing, and they can never seem to find the favorites tab in the phone application. A simple button would solve this, for now).

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out it is possible to create a profile in Apple Configurator that creates the button(s) you want, save it, and then send it to the person to install, which will then add the buttons. Totally painless on their end, so I can certainly deal with creating the profiles. Hope this helps someone else.

Short summary:

- Get Apple Configurator form the Mac App Store
- Turn on supervision and create a new profile on the general screen

  - Go to Web Clips
  - Add a new clip with a url in the form `tel:+12025551212`
  - Add more clips for more phone numbers
- Save and export the profile and mail it to the user

Comment: Kudos for finding an answer to your question! Could you expand the response with a link or short synopsis of this process to help someone else?

Answer (score 0):

In Apple Config, you can export it to email it to yourself, fairly simple! (Just open up the email on your iDevice and install!)